# ADFS 3.0 Need Powershell command to remove Homelink

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs

I am working on a Microsoft Windows Active Directory ADFS 3.0 (2012 R2 specifically) server. I was testing the Set-AdfsGlobalWebContent -Homelink and -Homelinktext options.  I'd like to now remove/blank these out.  I've tried using empty quotation marks and even an empty hashtable. The type of the Homelink property is System.Uri. I've not found another cmdlet that can do this (Remove-AdfsGlobalWebContent resets all the settings.)  Microsoft's TechNet covers adding these settings and how to remove other types of settings but not how to remove *individual* global web content properties.

Please do not provide references to older versions of ADFS as in 3.0 UI customizations are configured practically exclusively via Powershell.  It no longer uses IIS so you do not edit web pages directly.  Also, I am not attempting to create a script, just administer the product. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today.  Found nothing online, but running:

*set-adfsglobalwebcontent -homelink $null -homelinktext $null*

Did the trick.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much - it worked.  Thought of everything but $null.